# Adapting UCI lisp function with a loop to common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm currently trying to recreate an old program written in UCI Lisp using Common lisp but I'm not very fluent with Lisp.

The original function is:

```
(DE SETROLE (ROLE FILLER CD)
  (CONS (HEADER:CD CD)
        (APPEND (FOR (PAIR IN (ROLES:CD CD))
                    (WHEN (NOT (EQUAL (ROLE:PAIR PAIR) ROLE)))
                    (SAVE PAIR))
                (LIST (LIST ROLE FILLER]
```

Here's my common lisp interpretation:

```
(defun setrole (role filler cd)
 (cons (header/cd cd)
    (append (loop for pair in (roles/cd cd)
                do (when (not (equal (role/pair pair) role))
                (save pair)))
            (list (list role filler)))))
```

This is the error that comes up:

```
*** - EVAL: variable WHEN has no value
```

My initial thinking is that there is no equivalent 'save' function. The description of the function is:

> SETROLE Makes a new CD form with (ROLE FILLER) added or replacing the old (ROLE ...) pair.

Kindly help, I'm stumped

Comment: FWIW I'm almost sure from this sample that UCI Lisp is some flavour of InterLisp.

Comment: @tfb: UCI Lisp is a Lisp 1.6 + BBN Lisp (later renamed as Interlisp) extensions

Comment: @RainerJoswig: thank you!  Do you know if any user manuals &c survive (I like reading manuals for old Lisps...)

Comment: @tfb: hehe, sure: http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/stanford_lisp16_family#UCI_LISP_1.6_

Comment: tfb @RainerJoswig thanks a lot.. this seems really promising. 
Do you mind helping me install it? I've gotten to (https://www.saildart.org/[UCI,SYS]/) and (https://github.com/PDP-10/Interlisp-10/tree/master/files) but I'm not sure how to go about it. Thanks!!

Comment: @MuroriMutethia: where do you want to install it?

Comment: @RainerJoswig On my windows machine. If not, I could create a Linux virtual machine

Comment: @MuroriMutethia: that code seems to be from the 1970s. Did Windows or Linux exist then?

Comment: @RainerJoswig are there any viable alternatives?

Comment: @tfb is there a way to get interlisp on current computer systems? Thanks

Comment: @MuroriMutethia: that might be a question in its own right: I haven't used InterLisp since the last time I used a D-machine, which is a very long time ago now.

Comment: @MuroriMutethia: [LISPF4](https://github.com/blakemcbride/LISPF4) just might be interesting.  It builds for me but I did not play with it in any detail (I only used InterLisp on machines with fancy GUIs, I've never tried to talk to it with a command-line interface).  Also I suspect that LISPF4 has had the faerie components removed (or was before they got involved: the history is confused, as is everything involving the good folk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. There was a loose 'when' in the wild below the code.